# Couldn't delete file: Failure sftp

Tags: sftp, rm

this is what i get when i try to rm file on sftp server:

(when i run rename it's the same)

```
sftp> rm file
debug3: Sent message fd 3 T:7 I:34854
debug3: Received stat reply T:105 I:34854
Removing file
debug2: Sending SSH2_FXP_REMOVE "file"
debug3: Sent message fd 3 T:13 I:34855
debug3: SSH2_FXP_STATUS 4
Couldn't delete file: Failure
```

and file perms is:

```
-rw-rw-rw- 0 --NA-- --NA-- 6862 Sep  9 17:05 file
```

am i missing something?

somebody can help?

thanks in advance

Comment: What are the permissions on the directory containing the file?

Comment: i'll check on monday but i suppose something like 666 because i can write in

Comment: the directory is 777

Answer (score 1):

For certain networked file systems, like Hetzner backup space, files cannot be no longer deleted over SFTP if the disk space is 100% full. Trying to delete file using SFTP leads to this exact error message.

As a workaround one can extend the allocated backup space by ordering larger backup space plan.

Comment: Another possiblility is to replace an existing file with an empty file before deleting it. You may use the put command within the sftp shell environment, e.g. put <local_null_bytes_file> <remote_file_to_replace>